# how to know which anchor link is selected

Tags: php, html, css, database, e-commerce

I am building a website in which left side is restaurant name and in right side there is anchor link button.All button are produced from a single link inside a while loop.

```
while($dt=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
<a class='morebtn hvr-rectangle-in'  href='#'>Menu!</a>
}
```

All anchor button is same so how to know which button is get selected so that I can display menu page for that restaurant.

Comment: Either give them different id's and use jquery or directly in jquery also you can do that.

Comment: You must use Javascript / jQuery or make actual buttons / radio buttons out of that!

Comment: does this question really deserve 2 upvotes?!

Comment: `@raven23` check my example

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this

```
$i = 0;
while($dt=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<a class='morebtn hvr-rectangle-in' id = 'a_'.$i href='#'>Menu!</a>"; 
    $i++;
}
```

And then write javascript like this

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.morebtn hvr-rectangle-in').click(function(){
          var myId = this.id;
          //alert(myId);

        });
    });
</script>
```

then use that id.

Comment: then how to write js to check which one is clicked?

Comment: I have updated my answer hope that gives you some more direction.

Comment: i clicked on button but alert box is not showing just for reference.

Comment: If you pasted my code as is it won't show since I have commented altert in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem correctly. 
Maybe you can do it in JS using **scrollspy**.
Example:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: Actually you did not understood the problem. This is absolutely not the answer for his problem.